# intrarelational constraints sql

Tags: mysql, sql, assertion

I have two tables:
Primary School (Name, Number of Places, Address, City, State, Type)
Enrolment(School,Student,Date,Monthly Fee)
School is foreign key of name.
The type attribute can assume the value "Public"/"Equal" and in the
public school case the monthly fee must be NULL.
I tried with assertion but mysql apparently doesn't support create assertion statement. How can I do to implement this constraint?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this with a constraint and only two tables. MySQL does not support ASSERTION or any other type of inter-relational constraint (your question said intrarelational but you have reversed the meaning of intra and inter).

You could enforce it with a trigger, for example:

```
CREATE TRIGGER t BEFORE INSERT ON Enrolment FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
  DECLARE SchoolType VARCHAR(6);
  SELECT Type FROM PrimarySchool WHERE Name = NEW.School INTO SchoolType;
  IF SchoolType = 'Public' THEN
    SET NEW.MonthlyFee = NULL;
  END IF;
END
```

I have not tested this. It's meant as a rough example, only to demonstrate the concept.